# Arch reboots in Zoom due to ThinkPad overheat

Tags: linux, arch-linux, reboot, thinkpad

I have a fresh install of Arch Linux, and it's rebooting when I'm in a zoom call, not sure how it's related though.

Every time the reboot happens, I see:

```
root: clearing orphaned inode {number} (uid={number}, gid={number}, mode={number}, size{number})
root: clearing orphaned inode {number} (uid={number}, gid={number}, mode={number}, size{number})
```

I know I'm supposed to provide things that I tried, but I honestly don't know what I can do to find out what's going on. I saw a message before rebooting, but I didn't have the time to read it.

Swap memory:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15657        1380       13069         308        1207       13682
Swap:          1907           0        1907
```

Here it's the output of journal:

```
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:43:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:44:23 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:44:23 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:45:05 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-66 noise=9999 txrate=195000
Apr 09 14:46:24 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=175500
Apr 09 14:46:49 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:46:49 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:47:14 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:47:54 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-clean comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-clean comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch kernel: audit: type=1130 audit(1586454506.637:73): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-clean comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 09 14:48:26 arch kernel: audit: type=1131 audit(1586454506.637:74): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=systemd-tmpfiles-clean comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Apr 09 14:48:29 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:48:36 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:48:36 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU9: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU8: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU10: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU11: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:50 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:48:50 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:49:06 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:49:06 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:49:24 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:49:24 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:49:51 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=234000
Apr 09 14:49:51 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=234000
Apr 09 14:50:34 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:50:34 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:51:47 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:51:53 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:53:41 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-63 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 50339)
Apr 09 14:53:50 arch kernel: mce: CPU8: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:53:50 arch kernel: mce: CPU2: Core temperature/speed normal
Apr 09 14:54:14 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:54:23 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 14:54:46 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:54:46 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=6000
Apr 09 14:55:09 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:58:36 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-67 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU8: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU9: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU10: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU11: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:58:46 arch kernel: mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 60079)
Apr 09 14:59:08 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:59:08 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-69 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:59:22 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:59:22 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-65 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 14:59:48 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:59:48 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-71 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:59:51 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-75 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 14:59:51 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-75 noise=9999 txrate=390000
Apr 09 15:00:21 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 15:00:21 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-68 noise=9999 txrate=260000
Apr 09 15:00:44 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 15:00:44 arch wpa_supplicant[789]: wlp82s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-70 noise=9999 txrate=351000
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached (128 C), shutting down
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached (128 C), shutting down
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Attempting kernel_power_off: Temperature too high
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 191 at drivers/thermal/thermal_core.c:346 thermal_emergency_poweroff_func+0x11/0x30
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Modules linked in: uinput fuse rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg msr bnep snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_soc_core iwlmvm x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_compress coretemp ac97_bus joydev snd_pcm_dmaengine iTCO_wdt mac80211 mousedev uvcvideo kvm_intel 8250_dw iTCO_vendor_support btusb mei_hdcp btrtl snd_hda_intel videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm intel_rapl_msr i915 wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt libarc4 btintel videobuf2_memops nls_iso8859_1 kvm nls_cp437 videobuf2_v4l2 snd_intel_nhlt iwlwifi snd_hda_codec irqbypass vfat bluetooth i2c_algo_bit intel_cstate fat videobuf2_common intel_uncore snd_hda_core rtsx_pci_ms cfg80211 intel_rapl_perf videodev psmouse pcspkr input_leds e1000e i2c_i801 tpm_crb memstick thunderbolt drm_kms_helper mc
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  snd_hwdep ecdh_generic ecc snd_pcm mei_me tpm_tis intel_gtt intel_lpss_pci tpm_tis_core mei processor_thermal_device ucsi_acpi syscopyarea snd_timer intel_lpss tpm sysfillrect typec_ucsi intel_rapl_common sysimgblt idma64 fb_sys_fops intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal typec rng_core wmi thinkpad_acpi nvram ledtrig_audio rfkill snd battery soundcore ac int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone evdev int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid sg scsi_mod drm crypto_user agpgart ip_tables x_tables ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 dm_crypt dm_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel rtsx_pci_sdmmc serio_raw mmc_core atkbd libps2 aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd xhci_pci glue_helper xhci_hcd rtsx_pci i8042 serio
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 191 Comm: kworker/0:2 Not tainted 5.4.30-1-lts #1
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20QV0007US/20QV0007US, BIOS N2OET41W (1.28 ) 11/25/2019
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Workqueue: events thermal_emergency_poweroff_func
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: RIP: 0010:thermal_emergency_poweroff_func+0x11/0x30
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Code: 00 85 c0 0f 85 a1 36 00 00 eb d0 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 c7 c7 50 d7 f5 a3 e8 4d 74 99 ff <0f> 0b e8 68 0d 9c ff 48 c7 c7 a8 d7 f5 a3 e8 3a 74 99 ff 0f 0b e9
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffaddbc06f3e78 EFLAGS: 00010286
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffa40ed660 RCX: 0000000000000006
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000092 RDI: ffff8d066e217700
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: RBP: ffff8d066b638840 R08: 0000000000000538 R09: 0000000000000001
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: ffff8d066e229e80
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: R13: ffff8d066e22f700 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0ffff8d066e22f70
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8d066e200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: CR2: 0000282e2f997008 CR3: 0000000320cac005 CR4: 00000000003606f0
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: Call Trace:
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  process_one_work+0x1ea/0x3a0
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  worker_thread+0x4d/0x3f0
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  kthread+0xfb/0x130
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  ? process_one_work+0x3a0/0x3a0
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: ---[ end trace d8597bf5f8734089 ]---
Apr 09 15:01:11 arch kernel: kvm: exiting hardware virtualization
```

I found the relevant part. It looks a temperature issue.

Accordingly to the [docs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Extreme_(Gen_2)#Throttling_fix) there is a CPU throttling issue, but I already applied the fix upon installation - so I'm not sure what's happening. This is the status of the service:

```
● lenovo_fix.service - Stop Intel throttling
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lenovo_fix.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-09 15:03:26 -03; 35min ago
   Main PID: 645 (python3)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18766)
     Memory: 26.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/lenovo_fix.service
             └─645 python3 /usr/lib/throttled/lenovo_fix.py

Apr 09 15:03:26 arch systemd[1]: Started Stop Intel throttling.
Apr 09 15:03:28 arch lenovo_fix.py[645]: [I] Detected CPU architecture: Intel Kaby Lake (R)
Apr 09 15:03:28 arch lenovo_fix.py[645]: [I] Loading config file.
Apr 09 15:03:29 arch lenovo_fix.py[645]: [I] Starting main loop.
```

[HARDWARE MANUAL HERE](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p1_gen2_x1extreme_hmm_v1.pdf)

Comment: It's too fast, I would have to hold the camera for 15 - 30 minutes. Isn't there a way to check the logs?

Comment: I've just edited my question. About Hibernation - I don't have enabled, but I will enable it now.

Comment: No, don't enable Hibernation; it drastically increases the need for swap. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-swapspace#tb-recommended-system-swap-space

Comment: Ok, I will prep something to record it.

Comment: 1)  ext4 is AOK.  2) Please reboot from a LiveUSB or LiveDVD and run fsck -A -N to check the filesystem. 3) Your swap file should be 4GB or more. Would you consider expanding it? Instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_or_modify_a_swap_partition.3F

Comment: I would - could that be the cause of it? I'm using ext4 with luks encryption.

Comment: LUKS complicates this. See https://serverfault.com/a/375095 for how to run fsck on that drive.

Comment: Check my update if you can K7AAY

Comment: Your CPU overheats badly per log messages e.g., _thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached_ . PC Surgery's Needed. Make sure CPU cooling works w/ no vent blockage. If OK, then detach heatsink from CPU, clean old thermal material from both heatsink & CPU, and reapply a _small_ amount of new thermal material to the CPU before remounting the heatsink. Too much is bad! See https://bestthermalpaste.com/how-much-thermal-paste-is-too-much/ Just a small drop of thermal paste at the CPU center is needed to cover only the metal surface and _not_ anywhere else. See hardware manual bottom your question.